# Find cube root of $63$ to three decimal places

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find $\sqrt[3]{63}$ to three decimal places (without calculus or a calculator).

I am unable to find it. How to get the result by hand calculation? Please help.

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.google.es/search?q=cube+root+hand+calculation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=MnBtWvXNOobY8geAtIDYBQ)

Comment: Does "up to 3 decimal places mean 3.98 or $3.979$.

Answer (score 5):

$64^{1/3} = 4$, so the answer is a bit less than $4$.
$(4 - x)^3 = 64 - 48 x + 12 x^2 - x^3$.  Looking just at the first two terms, we want $x \approx 1/48 \approx 0.021$, i.e. the cube root is approximately $3.979$.  This does turn out to be accurate to three decimal places.

Comment: `does turn out to be accurate to three decimal places` May be worth emphasizing that this needs to be doublechecked against the definition of "*upto three decimal places*" being used. For example, a similar answer for $\,\sqrt[3]{6\color{red}{2}}\,$, instead, would give $x \approx 2/48 \approx 0.042$, i.e. the cube root approximately $3.958$. That's accurate to [*three significant digits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Rounding_and_decimal_places) as commonly understood, but the first *three decimals places* don't match since $\,\sqrt[3]{62}\simeq 3.95789 \ldots\,$.

Comment: But *"accurate to three decimal places"*  for the number 3.95789.. is 3.958 as you state the approximation of $\sqrt[3]{62}$ to be. @dxiv

Comment: @Nij That would be something for the OP to clarify. The question asks for the number "*to three decimal places*", and that could also mean finding the first three decimal digits to the right of the decimal point (without any rounding). While not so common, yet I've seen it used in that sense sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

$$63^{1/3}=(64-1)^{1/3}=4\left(1-\frac1{64}\right)^{1/3}
=4\left(1-\frac{1/3}{64}-\frac{1/9}{64^2}-\cdots\right)$$
(binomial theorem). Surely $4(1-1/(3\times 64))$ will be
close enough for your purposes.

Comment: +1 I'd only add a note about the radius of convergence being satisfied. We could've partitioned 63 in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $n = a + .1*b + .01*c + .001*d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers and $b,c,d$ are all between $-4$ and $5$.

We want to find $a,b,c,d$ so that $n^3$ is close to $63$ as possible.

$n^3 = a^3 + .1(3a^2b) + .01(3a^2c + 3ab^2) + .001(3a^2d + 6abc + b^3) + .0001(6abd + 3ac^2 + 3b^2c) + ....$

$3^3 = 27 < a^3 < 4^3 = 64$.  The closest we can get is $a = 4$.

So $63 = a^3 - 1$ and we want to get $.1(3a^2b)$ to be as  close to $-1$ as we can.  Or $48b \approx -10$.  The closest we can get is $b= 0$

So $63 = 64 - 1$ and we want $.01(3a^2c + 3ab^2) = .01(48c)$ to be as close to $-100$ as we can.  The closest we can get is $c = -2$ and $.01(48c) = -.96$.

$63 = 64 - .96 -.04$ so we want to get $.001(3a^2d + 6abc + b^3)=.001(48d)$ to be as close $-.04$ as we can.  And that would be $d = -1$

I suppose we should check the further more precise value just make sure there is a margin of error that made our choices wrong one.

$64 = 64 - .96 - .048 + .008$ so we want to verify $.0001(6abd + 3ac^2 +3b^2c) = .0001(12) = .00012$ does not alter the approximation by $.01$.  It doesn't.

So $n = 4 -.02 - .001 = 3.979$ is the best approximation within $3$ decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the binary subdivision / [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) method which is an equation approximation method which works for any continuous function:

1. We know it will be between 3 and 4, because $3^3 = 27\\4^3=64$ and $f(x)=x^3$ is a monotonically increasing function.
2. Start with step size $0.5$ : $(3.5)^3 = 42.875<63$
3. Halve step size $0.25$ and add it (since we were below): $(3.75)^3 = 52.738<63$
4. Halve step size $0.125$ and add it (since we were below): $(3.875)^3 = 58.186<63$
5. Keep doing this for a while... until the number you last added or subtracted was below $0.001$. We can estimate this with the 2 logarithm that it will happen after $\log_2(10^3) = 9.965 \approx 10$ iterations.